# Trying find the broken row in a tsv file using regular expression using sublime. I have 310 columns but file is breaking 206 tab

Tags: regex, file, unix

I am trying find the broken row in a tsv file using regular expression. I am using sublime. I have 310 columns but file is breaking 206 tab. I am processing this file in AWS glue. using pyspark.^

```
^[\t].*
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying? To decide whether a row is broken? To fix all broken rows? To show the number of the first broken row? To show the number of all broken rows? What have you done so far, what is happening, what would you want to happen instead? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I try to count all the tabs which was 309, using                                                
awk -F'\t' '{ print NF-1 }' input.txt > output.txt than I thought there must be a column which might be containing \\ or end of line character which is breaking the line -- I tried using grep command to filter it but it doesnt give any result  grep -nr "\\\\" hit_data.tsv